# About Python's built-in type is iterable object problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why don't all the built-in container types in Python set themselves as iterators?

Instead, an exclusive iterator is instantiated during the for loop?

Is it not good to implement the `__next__()` method directly at the bottom of these built-in types?

Doesn't this reduce memory consumption even more, define fewer classes and instantiate classes?

What would be the disadvantage of the following design?

```
class linearTypeContainer:
    def __init__(self, array):
        if isinstance(array, list) or isinstance(array, tuple):
            self.array = array
        else:
            raise TypeError("argument array must is linear container")

        self.index = 0
        self.len = len(self.array)
        self.iter = False # ❶

    def __iter__(self):
        if self.iter: # ❷
            self.index = 0
        self.iter = True
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.index < self.len:
            retDataItem = self.array[self.index]
            self.index += 1
            return retDataItem
        else:
            self.index = 0
            raise StopIteration


container = linearTypeContainer(list(range(5)))

for item in container:
    print(item)
    if container.index == 3:
        break

print("*" * 20)

for item in container:
    print(item)

# 0
# 1
# 2
# ********************
# 0
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
```

The bottom layer of Python is closer to the following code implementation:

```
class linearTypeContainer:
    def __init__(self, array):
        if isinstance(array, list) or isinstance(array, tuple):
            self.array = array
        else:
            raise TypeError("argument array must is linear container")

    def __iter__(self):
        return linearContainer_iterator(self.array)  # ❶


class linearContainer_iterator:
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.index = 0
        self.array = array
        self.len = len(self.array)

    def __next__(self):
        if self.index < self.len:
            retDataItem = self.array[self.index]
            self.index += 1
            return retDataItem
        else:
            raise StopIteration

    def __iter__(self):  # ❷
        return self


container = linearTypeContainer([i for i in range(10)])
for i in container:
    print(i)
print(list(container))
```

Comment: One immediate issue comes to mind: your implementation is not thread-safe, so multiple threads iterating on the object will interfere with each other. Providing a separate iterator object solves that.

Comment: Even in the absence of threads - if the object was its own iterator, then you couldn't even have two nested loops over the same object.

Comment: some things are their own iterator, such as open files. for example if you `break` out of a `for line in file_handle:` loop, then call another loop `for line in file_handle` it will pick back up where it stopped.

Comment: This is really a detail that is easy to overlook

Answer (score 3):

If lists were iterators, you couldn't easily compute products:

```
some_list = [1,2,3]
for i in some_list:
    for j in some_list:
        print(i, j)
```

With seperate list iterators, the above produces

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 1
3 2
3 3
```

If the list were its own iterator, you'd get

```
1 2
1 3
```

The outer loop would set `i == 1`, leaving *only* `2` and `3` for the inner loop to iterate over. Once the inner loop completes, there would be nothing left for the outer loop, causing it to terminate.

(You can simulate this by creating an explicit iterator to share:

```
some_list_itr = iter(some_list_itr)
for i in some_list_itr:
    for j in some_list_itr:
        print(i,j)
```

Every iterator should be iterable by having its `__iter__` method return `self`.)

Memory consumption is not an issue. A list iterator only has a reference to the underlying list, not a copy of it. This is why you shouldn't *mutate* a list while iterating over it, as this will confuse even a single iterator that expects its list not to change during iteration.

Comment: I did not consider the problem of nested loops, thank you very much

Comment: In fact, this is exactly what happens if we add the line `some_list = iter(some_list)` before the for loops.

Comment: @jfaccioni Good point; added that as a concrete example.

Answer (score 2):

"Iterators" get exhausted, but "Iterables" don't. Most of the time we want to iterate several times over a `list` for example. In that case I think it's more expensive.

If they were Iterators:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
lst_iter = iter(lst)
for i in lst_iter:
    print(i)
for i in lst_iter:
    print(i)
```

Second loop doesn't print anything. so we have to build the list again ! This is I think the reason why built-in container types are "Iterables".

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in lst:
    print(i)
for i in lst:
    print(i)
```

Now it's perfectly fine to iterate several times over it. By the way iterators doesn't consume much memory, they are lazy, they yield items as needed and just keep the state of them.

Comment: My example 1 can perform multiple for loops at the same level, but the thread safety question answered upstairs is indeed ignored by me. I think this should be the key point.

Comment: @YunYaJun + also nested loops on the same object, in your implementation, it keeps running infinitely.  The outer loop's index, turns back to zero every time the inner starts.